# EclipseでJavaScriptのステップ実行を試したい

Tags: javascript, eclipse

EclipseのPHPのプロジェクトで、Webページに読み込まれるJSがあります。
Eclipseのデバッグ操作でJSについても、ステップ実行できればなぁと考えますが無理なのでしょうか？

何かのプラグインが足りないのでしょうか？
デバッグ実行しても、ブレークポイントで停まりません。
現状の当方のデバッグ構成画面は以下のとおりです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ちなみにブラウザ（IE）の開発ツールの使い方が分からなく、Eclipseでどうにかならないか模索しだしました。

【追記】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 図の38行目ではなく40行目あたりにブレーク入れても、止まりませんか？

Answer (score 1):

> Eclipseのデバッグ操作でJSについても、ステップ実行できればなぁと考えますが無理なのでしょうか？

できます。

[Eclipse for PHP Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/oxygen3a)を使っているのであれば、それに[JavaScript Development Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)（JSDT）が含まれていて、このパッケージにJSDT Debug（以下）があるので、デバッグできるはずです（EclipseでPHPの開発したことが無いので、詳しくは知りませんが）。

> JSDT Debug - includes support for debugging JavaScript using Rhino and Crossfire

JSDTがインストールされていないのであれば、[Eclipse Web Developer Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0)などのJSDTを含むプラグインをインストールすればいいと思います。

ブラウザ標準の開発ツールで十分な気もしますが。

Comment: ご返答をありがとうございます。現在自宅で問題の端末が手元にない状況なので、JSDTも間違いなくインストールされている前提でお話します。ひょっとしてJQueryを利用していると、ブレークポイントを明示的に示した部分で停まらないですか？ブラウザ標準の開発ツールも停まらないように見え。使い方がわかっていないだけかも知れませんが

Comment: そんなことは無いと思います。少なくともブラウザ標準の開発ツールのブレークポイントで止まらないなら、そこを通ってないのかもしれませんね。

Comment: お付き合い頂きありがとうございます。
JSDTの存在を確認致しました。当方の環境が正しい状況かご確認頂ければと思い、本文に図を追加させて頂きました。
また、もう一つ追加した図ではデバッグの実行操作方法になります。
最後に追加した図では、デバッグ操作を行っているのにも関わらず当該のJSからブレークポイントを通過して、Webページにダイアログが現われている状態を示しています。
通過している・通過していないの問題ではなく、見方・操作を誤っているのでしょうか？
ちなみに先に添付したデバッグ構成の画像のとおり、「ファイル」の定義部分では、当該Webサイトの入り口のページを設定しています。
現在焦点を充てているWebページではありません。設定した入り口のページから遷移して焦点を充てているWebページに入ってきます。

Comment: @saya24 おそらく、今の方法では、PHP用のデバッガーしか起動しないのだと思います。[このページ](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+and+JavaScript+code+at+the+same+time+in+PhpStorm)にあるように、JetBrainsのPhpStormを使えば、サーバーサイドのPHPとクライアントサイドのJSを同時にデバッグできるようです。これと同じことをeclipseでもできるのではないかと思いますが、試してみないと何とも言えませんね。

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます。わざわざ同時にデバッグを達成する方法を調べて頂き
大変申し訳なかったのですが．．．同時でなくて構わないので、
皆さんがEclipse上で　JSのデバッグ・ステップ実行を行えているのは
どういった設定をEclipse上で行い達成されているのでしょうか？

デバッグ構成をPHP用とJS用で切替えるような運用も全然ありと考えます。
そもそもどういう設定からJSのデバッグが達成できるのか全くみえないのです．．．。

Comment: @saya24 クライアントサイドのJSのデバッグ（ステップ実行）をEclipseで行う必要性を感じなかったので、ブラウザの開発ツールを使っていました。私も他の人がどうしてるか聞いてみたいですね。